# Hiding button on tableview on a particular cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have created table. On each cell I am adding button depending upon the value from flag array.
Here is my code for adding button on cell

```
if ([[self.flags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
isEqualToString:@"false"])
    {
        UIButton *btnFlag = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnFlag addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(flagButtonPressed:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        btnFlag.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [btnFlag setTitle:@"flag" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnFlag.frame = CGRectMake(230, 40, 50, 20);
        [cell addSubview:btnFlag];


    }else if ([[self.flags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"true"])
{
     UIButton *btnFlag = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnFlag setHidden:YES];
    [cell addSubview:btnFlag];
}


-(void)flagButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
        indexPathToCell = [self.cotDetailsTbl indexPathForCell:owningCell];
     //    some stuff    }
```

In the above method Im calling the api and depending upon the response obtained Im replacing  the value in flag array from false to true. Once the value in flag array becomes true Im reloading table.

But the problem is when Im reloading table the button still appears its not hidden

Thanks

Comment: how can you replace value in your array ??

Comment: have u checked you are getting correct values in array.I mean whether your array is updating correctly.

Comment: [self.flags replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPathToCell.row withObject:@"true"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your else part you again creating a new instance of button using  
`UIButton *btnFlag = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` 
instead you need the existing `UIbutton` instance and set it to hidden.

Try using the following:

In if statement, assign a tag to each button

```
btnFlag.tag = indexPath.row
```

Now. in else do the following find the button by its tag and set hidden :

```
else if ([[self.flags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"true"])
{
 UIButton *btnFlag = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
 [btnFlag setHidden:YES];
}
```